# apache2 reload causes 404 until reopening browser

Tags: php, apache

Trying to make our redeploy scenario deploy with 0 seconds downtime on apache/php/codeigniter we do the following:

- We send a zip files to the server and unzips them in a new appfolder /app_timestamp
- We overwrite the existing apache conf for the (only virtual host info) pointing to /app_timestamp
- We trigger an /etc/init.d/apache2 reload to reload the configuration.

Everything works perfect except that a user already on the site suffers a 404 error after deployment. If the user closes his browser and opens up the same url again it starts working again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having the apache conf point to /app_timestamp, have it point to /app_latest and create /app_latest to be a symlink to /app_timestamp. When deploying a new package, unzip as before into /app_timestamp. Then simply move the symlink to point to the new /app_timestamp. No apache reload required.

Comment: There is still a little problem.

Comment: Thanks Alex! There is still a little problem. I'm using ln -sfn appname_timestamp appname. I refresh the page all the time and just when it deploys the page turns blank (no 404) and then another refresh and it works.. It is much better but still not 100%. Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm not sure, what's your Apache log say?

Comment: Hi again! Thanks for your help. Log says: Mon Oct 17 03:24:30 2011] [error] [client 85.197.173.196] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/root/webapps/frontend_test/index.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in Unknown on line 0, referer: http://frontend.domain.com/tellmemore
Happens on both FF and chrome. Hitting the refresh button in the browser reloads the page correct.

Comment: Using APC or similar? Maybe you do have to reload Apache after all, to  clear the cache.